# Parse xml into array

Tags: php, xml

I have below XML string. I want to use it tag. I tried **simplexml_load_string** but this gives me below warnings.

PHP Code

```
 <?
$data='<?xml version="1.0" ?><ns00:category xmlns:ns00="urn:productlist">DEX</ns00:category><ns00:type xmlns:ns00="urn:productlist">Type A</ns00:type>';
$xml=simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Warnings

```
simplexml_load_string(): X&lt;/ns00:category&gt;&lt;ns00:type xmlns:ns00=&quot;urn:productlist&quot;&gt;Type A&lt;/ns00:type&gt;&lt;cat&gt; in C:\wamp\www\wsdl4\xml.php on line 3
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag cat line 1
simplexml_load_string(): ^
```

I wan to use this xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the XML you're using isn't in a "propper" format,

If the XML is generated by you, so you must fix the XML writter, use a function that generate it, or just follow the [XML Core Standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/core)

If the XML is NOT generated by you, so you will need to do some workarounds, I did many, I'd suggest you to:

SMALL FILE:

> -> Read it by simple get_file_contents()
>
> -> Split it in any way you need (REGEX for fast development, hardcoded switch-cases/strpos/substr for better performance)

BIG FILE bigger than 500MB:

> -> Try fixing the XML format using linux commands like SED, AWK or even XMLLINT before parsing it;

You could also try this:

> SimpleXMLReader, as it reads the XML step/by/step, maybe you didn't even need the workarounds .. https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader the only problem is that this is slow like hell, unusable for my applications.